# Numbers of solutions $e^x=-x^2+2x+5 $

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $e^x=-x^2+2x+5 $ have exactly two solutions.

Is it enoguht that Vertex of the parabola is over $y=e^x$ and arms of it looks down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. More rigorously, we can use the Intermediate Value Theorem (IVT) to prove that **at least two** solutions exist. Then we can use Rolle's Theorem to prove that **at most two** solutions exist.

---

Let $f(x) = e^x + x^2 - 2x - 5$. Note that $f$ is continuous for all $x$. Furthermore, note that:
\begin{align*}
f(-10) &= e^{-10} + 100 + 20 - 5 = e^{-10} + 115 > 0 \\
f(0) &= 1 + 0 - 0 - 5 = -4 < 0 \\
f(10) &= e^{10} + 100 - 20 - 5 = e^{-10} + 75 > 0 \\
\end{align*}

Hence, by IVT, we have $f(x)=0$ for some $x \in (-10,0)$ and for some $x \in (0,10)$.

---

Now suppose instead that the equation $f(x)=0$ has three solutions $a<b<c$. Since $f$ is continuous and differentiable everywhere and $f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=0$, the conditions of Rolle's Theorem are satisfied. Hence, we know that for some $r\in (a,b)$ and for some $s \in (b,c)$, we have $f'(r) = f'(s) = 0$.

We will now apply Rolle's Theorem a second time to the equation $f'(x)=0$. Since the function $f'(x)=e^x + 2x - 2$ is continuous and differentiable everywhere and $f'(r) = f'(s) = 0$, the conditions of Rolle's Theorem are satisfied. This yields $f''(t)=e^t + 2=0$ for some $t \in (r,s)$. But this is impossible, since $e^t$ is nonnegative for all $t$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little out of the blue, but...

Since $e^x > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there can only be two points where RH intersects $e^x$ since $e^x = -x^2+2x+5 \implies x^2-2 x+e^x = 5$.

If we rewrite $x^2-2 x+e^x = 5$ as $x^2-2 x+e^x = y$, observe that its minima is at $x^2-2 x+e^x = W(\frac{e}{2}) (W(\frac{e}{2})+2)-1,\, x = 1-W(\frac{e}{2})$

where $W(n)$ denotes the Lambert W function.

As $x$ tends from $1-W(\frac{e}{2}) \to \infty$ or $1-W(\frac{e}{2}) \to -\infty$, $y\to\infty$, thus it is easy to see that $e^x = -x^2+2x+5$ has only two solutions.